# Every first request gives an Error 500. Websphere application server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere

Can you help me with this please.

I got a problem with my Java Application, 
In live, For every First request to url given me an **Error 500**. For second request onwards its working fine until we leave it idle for some minutes.

***Details:--***

Java 4.1
WebSphere Application server v5

**Settings in Admin (WebSphere server):--**

Starting weight = 10000.

class loader Mode = Parent first.

Indication showing = Partially started.

So,  Suggest me What to do.

Thanks.

**More Info:--**

War file inside Ear file.

Package Directory:-- app.Ear --> app1.War

Comment: Hi, I found it out. the actual error is not 500. it just redirecting to page error500. by "302 found" redirect. I found this from "wheregoes.com"

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some uninitialized value somewhere in your code and that is the reason for crash.

Make sure you are logging exceptions ( a NullPointerException will be ) and check the log file.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a standalone application or does it have a database call in there somewhere?

If the latter then check the logs for StaleConnectionExceptions. Once thrown this will refresh the datasource however the first request fails, usually in the morning on our systems.

If you do see the above then simply catch and handle them, some sort of try while retry in the catch block.

Would be useful to know what is being thrown in the logs though..